# how to add link tag in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to display another page when I click the link. I am using the following code. But I didn't get the expected output. It says `No route matches "/wel.html" with          {:method=>:get}` what can I do? Please help me.

```
<%= link_to "Click here", "wel.html" %>
```

Comment: It appears your keyboard doesn't work right, especially the shift and spacebar keys.

Answer (score 0):

ERB stands for "embedded Ruby", you can't have a link to an ERB file.

If you are pointing to an internal page, you should have a route to that through a controller action to make it actively reachable.

If you are pointing to an external source, you need to provide the full path, i.e. "http://...".

I'd suggest you take a look at a [Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) before starting to build an app.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to open `wel.html` file in your app, then you need to put it into `public` folder and change your link to `<%= link_to "Click here", "/wel.html" %>`.

Comment: thank you.it is working.but i didn't get the web bage . its show the code what i typed there.

Comment: Does it have a valid HTML layout?

Comment: this is my 'wel.html.erb' file<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: Can you try to remove `.erb` from the extension and leave it just as `wel.html`?

Comment: Thank you.It is working.if i need to display 'wel.html.erb' file,what can i do?

Comment: You should create a controller, action, view and route to render your template. Please, mark answer as accepted, if it helped you. Thanks!